# Deeplab v3+ Shape mismatch in tuple component

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape, image-segmentation, deeplab

I have trained deeplab v3+ on `ADE20K`dataset,and got the trained `ckpt`jlogs and `events`logs.But when I run `eval.py`and `vis.py`on `ADE20K`,I got the following errors about shape:

```
Shape mismatch in tuple component 1. Expected [513,513,3], got [513,683,3]
```

These are my `eval`scripts and `vis` scripts:

`eval`scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ../

python deeplab/eval.py  \
--logtostderr \
--eval_split="val" \
--model_variant="xception_65" \
--atrous_rates=6 \
--atrous_rates=12 \
--atrous_rates=18 \
--output_stride=16 \
--decoder_output_stride=4 \
--eval_crop_size=513 \
--eval_crop_size=513 \
--checkpoint_dir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/exp/train_on_train_set/train/  \
--eval_logdir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/exp/train_on_train_set/eval/  \
--dataset_dir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/tfrecord/ \
--max_number_of_iterations=1
```

`vis`scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ../

python deeplab/vis.py  \
--logtostderr \
--vis_split="val" \
--model_variant="xception_65" \
--atrous_rates=6 \
--atrous_rates=12 \
--atrous_rates=18 \
--output_stride=16 \
--decoder_output_stride=4 \
--vis_crop_size=513 \
--vis_crop_size=513 \
--checkpoint_dir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/exp/train_on_train_set/train/  \
--vis_logdir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/exp/train_on_train_set/vis/  \
--dataset_dir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/tfrecord/ \
--max_number_of_iterations=1
```

And my `train`scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ../

python deeplab/train.py  \
--logtostderr  \
--training_number_of_steps=150000  \
--train_split="train"  \
--model_variant="xception_65"  \
--atrous_rates=6  \
--atrous_rates=12  \
--atrous_rates=18  \
--output_stride=16  \
--decoder_output_stride=4  \
--train_crop_size=513  \
--train_crop_size=513  \
--train_batch_size=2  \
--min_resize_value=513  \
--max_resize_value=513  \
--resize_factor=16  \
--dataset="ade20k"  \
 --tf_initial_checkpoint=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/init_models        /deeplabv3_xception_ade20k_train/model.ckpt.index  \
--train_logdir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/exp/train_on_train_set/train  \
--dataset_dir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/tfrecord/
```

Is there any thing I set wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the arguments used in your sh-script match the arguments required by your current code version.

Not long ago you had to pass two separated values for the crop size buy the current implementation uses

```
--eval_crop_size="513,513" \
```

or

```
 --vis_crop_size="513,513" \
```

(taken from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/local_test.sh))

Hope this helps ;). If not try to print the crop values in the vis.py/eval.py script and look if the are passed correctly.